# if input text is being entered'empty hide label, when the button is pressed show label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, textbox, label

is there a way where I can show the label only when the button is pressed and hide it when the textbox is empty or is being re-entered? 
I am using asp.net to develop the web app

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using JavaScript functions and link them to OnClick/OnChange events of button/textbox.

Answer (score 0):

take that textbox in panel and on button click event you can write textbox ID.visible = true else textbox ID.visible = false